# How to choose the driver to serialize/deserialize with jmsserializer

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have an object which I serialize using annotations. It works fine.

If I am using yaml configuration, it works fine also.

My problem is I want to use both in different context. Lets say that in controller one, I want to use the annotation configuration and in controller two, I want to use the yaml configuration. I want to do that because I need to have different field names in those outputs.

- I tried to override the serializer with a new instance using only the annotation.
- I change jmsserializer service configuration to not use specific drivers. It worked but I cannot choose which one to activate dynamically.
- I tried to select the driver in the container but I couldn't make it work.

Is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can achieve this.

But if you to want expose a property differently, you can create different views of your object by using an exclusion strategy.

Example :

```
/**
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FooBar
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @JMS\Groups({"foo"})
     */
    protected $name; // output 'name'

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @JMS\SerializedName("foo_bar_name")
     * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getName", setter="setName")
     * @JMS\Groups({"bar"})
     */
    protected $fooName; // output 'foo_bar_name'

    // ...

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->address = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Like this, the property can be serialised in two different names :

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize(new FooBar(), 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('foo')));

//will output $name as 'name'

$serializer->serialize(new FooBar(), 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('bar')));

//will output $fooName as 'foo_bar_name'
```

Note the `@JMS\SerializedName` is not mandatory, you can use it for custom names.

See more at the [Exclusion strategies](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) part of the documentation.

Hope this could be an alternative for you.

Comment: I though of that but it wont work in my use case since I want the same properties exposed with different names.

Comment: ? This is what I show you.  `$fooName` returns the value of `$name` in serialisation. It's just a fake property with a different name, using the same setter and getter. Also, `$fooName` always returns the value of `$name` .

Comment: I see. I will consider that. Thanks

Comment: It's cleaner than create two different views of your object in two different formats, and it represents less work.